# Display last child categories

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I would print only the list child categories.

Example :

**News --> Press Release --> Viking Cruises**

I would print Viking Cruises

I have this code that works, but print the entire tree of categories not last.

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category();

      $separator = ' ';

      $output = '';

      if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {

          foreach( $categories as $category ) {

              $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( 
$category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html ($category->name) . '</a>' . 
$separator;
          }

          echo trim( $output, $separator );

      } ?>
```

thanks for help!

Comment: did you want last subcategory to show?

Comment: yes, last subcategory.

Comment: Please Try my answer

Comment: Read this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54462/display-the-deepest-child-category-from-category-x-in-loop#152928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code, Please try it. Hope it will work for you.

```
 <?php $categories = get_the_category();
     $separator = ' ';
     $output = '';
     if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
     foreach( $categories as $category ) {
      $children=get_categories(array( 'parent' => $category->cat_ID ));
          if ( count($children) == 0 ) {
            $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( 
            $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html ($category->name) . 
           '</a>' . $separator;
         }
    }

         echo trim( $output, $separator );

  } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Works, but before your code print News --> Press Release --> Viking Cruises, now Press Release --> Viking Cruises... I would print only Viking Cruises.

Comment: @emiliano, enjoy

Comment: How I can print only last?

Comment: Do you mean the last one  "Viking Cruises"?

Comment: Okay, Please see this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55890/name-of-last-category-level-for-a-post

Comment: I see thanks... but I'm not able to add this in php code... you can help me? thanks

Comment: Do you mean in core php?

Comment: I mean in my existing code, that you have just updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166444/discussion-between-gufran-hasan-and-emiliano).