# Get WordPress Current Category ID and Top Level Parent Category ID on all category and post templates

Tags: php, wordpress

Say you have WordPress site with for example with the following structure:

```
Dog (Top Level Category)
-Boxer (Sub Level Category)
--Brindle (Third Level Category)
--Reverse Brindle (Third Level Category)
-Golden Retriever (Sub Level Category)
-Labrador (Sub Level Category)

Cat (Top Level Category)
-Siamese (Sub Level Category)
--Siamese Black (Third Level Category)
--Siamese White (Third Level Category)
-Bengal (Sub Level Category)
-Ragdoll (Sub Level Category)
```

Attempting to develop a function to add to all the page templates such as category.php, single.php, etc, so that the side menu will show the full category hierarchy based on your location. Such as if you are viewing Dog category, or boxer, or brindle it would show the same full Dog menu like above with each linked to their respective categories and the one you are on would have an active class.

Also at the top of the page to output Top Level Category and the category you are on. Such as if on Reverse Brindle would say, "Dog > Reverse Brindle" or if on Dog would just say, "Dog" or if on Boxer would say "Dog > Boxer.

Have it sort of working but with a lot of redundant code and on same pages not working as expected.

Comment: I think you can use the concept of getting categories by a parent category id. If category has a parent category then it will give you details. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Gurfran If you have working code that you feel works, feel free to post as an answer and can test and mark as the answer if it does. Thanks!

Comment: I think this code will be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168105/display-last-child-categories/49168284#49168284

Comment: @GufranHasan That post seems to be about listing child categories. However, this SO is for getting the parent category id, no matter if on category, or sub category or or post page.

Comment: Is it helpful for you?

Comment: Sorry not sure if you saw my above comment, but that link does not apply to this post. If you have an example that does, feel free to post as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way you can display a whole structured list of all the categories using [wp_list_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

```
<?php
//Get whatever object we're working with (category or post?)
$thisObj = get_queried_object();

//If it's a post, get the category ID
if(!is_null($thisObj->ID)){
    $currentCat = get_the_category();
    $currentCatID = $currentCat[0]->cat_ID;
}

//If it's a category, get the ID a different way
elseif(!is_null($thisObj->term_id)){
    $currentCatID = $thisObj->term_id;
}

//Call wp_list_categories to echo the list of categories
$args = array(
    'current_category' => $currentCatID,  //This assigns the "current-cat" class to the correct item in the list so you can style it differently
    'child_of' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'name',
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Then you can style the active category in the list with this:

(There are also quite a few more classes you can work with to style the rest of the list. Just take a look at the HTML it produces)

```
.current-cat{
    /* whatever you want */
}
```

This should do it for the top of your page:

```
<?php
$thisObj = get_queried_object(); // Find out what we're displaying (Category or post?)

if(!is_null($thisObj->ID)){  // If it's a post, get the category ID
    $currentCat = get_the_category();
    $currentCatID = $currentCat[0]->cat_ID;
}
elseif(!is_null($thisObj->term_id)){  // If it's a category, get the ID a different way
    $currentCatID = $thisObj->term_id;
}

// Get the name of the Category we're starting with
$currentCatName = get_cat_name($currentCatID);

//Get the ID then the name of the highest parent Category
$topParentID = end(get_ancestors($currentCatID, 'category'));
$topParentName = get_cat_name($topParentID);


if(!$topParentName){  // If we're already at the highest category, just save the name
    $finalAnswer = $currentCatName;
}
else{  // Otherwise, display "Top Parent > Current Cat"
    $finalAnswer = $topParentName . ' > ' . $currentCatName;
}
echo $finalAnswer; //Ta-da!
```

Comment: Got it working but merging this with what I have. Now working perfectly! Will award the bounty as soon as it lets me in 11 hours.